# About a proof of the fact "An interval in $\mathbb{R}$ is connected".

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, connectedness

I am reading "A Course in Analysis vol.3" by Kazuo Matsuzaka.

The author proved the following proposition as follows:

> An interval in $\mathbb{R}$ is connected

Proof:
Let $I$ be an interval in $\mathbb{R}$.
We assume that $I = P \cup Q$, $P \cap Q = \emptyset$, $P, Q$ are both non-empty and open in $I$.
Let $a \in P$ and $b \in Q$.
Since $a \ne b$, $a < b$ or $a > b$.
Without loss of generality, we can assume that $a < b$.
Since $I$ is an interval, $[a, b] \subset I$.
Let $M := [a, b] \cap P$.
Since $a \in M$, $M \ne \emptyset$. $b$ is an upper bound of $M$.
So, there exists $c := \sup M$ and $a \leq c \leq b$.
Since $c \in I$, $c \in P$ or $c \in Q$.
If $c \in P$, $c < b$.
Since $P$ is open in $I$, $P = P' \cap I$ for some set $P'$ which is open in $\mathbb{R}$.
So, $c < c + \epsilon < b, c + \epsilon \in P$ for sufficiently small $\epsilon > 0$.
$\cdots$

> I think we don't need the sentence "***Since $P$ is open in $I$, $P = P' \cap I$ for some set $P'$ which is open in $\mathbb{R}$.***" in the proof.

Is the above sentence really necessary for the proof?

My proof without the above sentence is here:

> Proof:
>   Let $I$ be an interval in $\mathbb{R}$.
>   We assume that $I = P \cup Q$, $P \cap Q = \emptyset$, $P, Q$ are both non-empty and open in $I$.
>   Let $a \in P$ and $b \in Q$.
>   Since $a \ne b$, $a < b$ or $a > b$.
>   Without loss of generality, we can assume that $a < b$.
>   Since $I$ is an interval, $[a, b] \subset I$.
>   Let $M := [a, b] \cap P$.
>   Since $a \in M$, $M \ne \emptyset$. $b$ is an upper bound of $M$.
>   So, there exists $c := \sup M$ and $a \leq c \leq b$.
>   Since $c \in I$, $c \in P$ or $c \in Q$.
>   If $c \in P$, $c < b$.
>   If $c < x < b$, then $x \in I$.
>   $P$ is open in $I$.
>   So, there exists $\epsilon' > 0$ such that if $c < x < c + \epsilon' < b$ and $x \in I$, then $x \in P$.
>   But if $c < x < b$ then $x \in I$.
>   So, there exists $\epsilon' > 0$ such that if $c < x < c + \epsilon' < b$, then $x \in P$.
>   Let $c < c + \epsilon < c + \epsilon'$.
>   Then, $c < c + \epsilon < b$ and $c + \epsilon \in P$.
>   $\cdots$

Comment: Are you sure it isn't “...$P = P' \cap I$ for some set $P'$ ...”?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Thank you very much. I was wrong. I edited that.

Comment: OK, that makes more sense.  Can you complete the proof without that sentence?  If so, it's not necessary.

Comment: How do you know that $c+\epsilon \in P$ for small enough $\epsilon>0$?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Thank you for your advice. I completed the proof without that sentence.

Comment: @N.S. Thank you for your comment. I completed the proof without that sentence.

Comment: This line "So, there exists $\epsilon'>0$ such that if $c<x<c+\epsilon'<b$ and $x\in I$, then $x \in P$" is really rephrasing the line you are trying to avoid.

Comment: @N.S. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It feels like that sentence is trying to justify the next one you write: *So, $c<c+\varepsilon<b$, $c+\varepsilon \in P$, for sufficiently small $\varepsilon$*.

As long as this is clear from you from the fact that $P$ is open in $I$ then it's all good and you don't need that sentence... unless there is something else later in the proof that appears to be using it too.

Comment: "It's clear" is not a proof...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Anguepa.

Comment: @NeedForHelp I find that often writing a proof is explaining something until you feel like you can say "it is clear at this point".